# How to "disable" certain paragraph types?

Tags: paragraphs

I am not sure if this is possible or not (which is why I have come to you fine folks), but I have searched for this and still haven't found an answer...

Is it possible to just "disable" paragraph types in a D8 site instead of deleting them? I know you can "disable" content types in D8 and D7, but I just want to disable some of the paragraph types that we have on our customer's sites without completely deleting them in case the need for them happens to come up from individual customers.

When I go to the full list of paragraph types, the only options that I'm given are:

- Manage Fields
- Manage Form
- Manage Form Display
- Manage Display
- Edit
- Delete

So, any help with this would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just to say, 'nope. not possible.' :)

Thank You!
Nicole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure this is. Per field. So let's say you have a "Paragraphs" field (field_paragraphs in the screenshot below) in the "Article" content type. Then you edit this field and there you have to select which paragraph types you want to include or exclude.

[image]

Comment: Check the confirmation page when doing this though, sometimes it can have unintended consequences on config changes.